# How to create a QGIS road style for OSM data?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

I am trying to use qgis to visualize the shortest path algorithm's result. I managed to import the osm map into qgis

[image]

But I think it looks kind of different. I was referring to this [link](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/) and she has this nice map like this

[image]

So I tried to import the database creating using osm2po. And this is what I got

[image]

This is still different from the one seen at [link](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/). I know the region is different, but still

I followed the same step as defined in link [link](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/). I also used the same file for austria and imported it into my database. I changed the style as well and this is what I got.

[image]

Now the roads and highways in the link [link](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/) look nice and fine. However, in my case they look kind of overlapped. Why is it so?

Comment: please change the title of your question as it does not reflect what you are asking in the body. Maybe something like " symbolizing OSM in QGIS for routing"

Answer (score 1):

As you already discovered, the general idea is to create a symbol out of two layers: one layer with a thicker grey line and on top of that a thinner white line.

[image]

To avoid "overlapping", activate "Symbol levels" in the upper right corner of the style tab.

Comment: I fixed the overlapping issue. However, I didn't get the two layer symbol method. Could you please attach some screenshots?